Missing or insufficient permissions when uploading an image to Firebase Storage
So, I've been struggling hard with this error... let me explain my scenario first:
These are my firebase storage rules:
rules_version = "2";
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
        // allow read, update, create: if true;
      // allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
      allow read, create, update: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}

And this is my code when uploading the image:
async saveGuestSignature(signature: string) {
      const commonStore = useCommonStore();
      const authStore = useAuthStore();
      const storageRef = ref(storage, `/guests-signatures/${commonStore.hotel}/${authStore.uid}.png`);
      const b64 = signature.substring(signature.indexOf(',') + 1);
      try {
        const snapshot = await uploadString(storageRef, b64, 'base64');
        return await getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref)
      } catch (error) {
        await saveErrorLog(commonStore.hotel, authStore.uid, 'saveSignature', error);
        Notify.create({
          type: 'negative',
          timeout: 15000,
          icon: 'mdi-alert',
          message: `Un error sucedió al intentar guardar la firma: ${error}`,
          actions: [
            {
              label: 'Ok',
              color: 'white',
              handler: () => {
                /* ... */
              }
            }
          ]
        });
        return null;
      }
    },

commonStore.hotel and authStore.uid are indeed defined, and the user is certaninly authenticated before this upload operation is performed.
Most of the time, it works, but for some users, I'm getting this error randomly:

FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

This function as you can see uploads the image (base64 string) and returns the downloadURL or if fails it should return null, in order to save this to the database.
I've tried changing the rules, and it seems that if read, write: true is set to allow all read and write operations, it works, but this is obviously not the idea.
I know it seems like it can be an authentication issue, but, I'm pretty sure the user is authenticated, since there are more operations to the firestore database for example which needs the user to be authenticated too and those work perfectly.
To add more context:
This is the way I authenticate users:
async doLogin(email: string, password: string) {
  const guestStore = useGuestStore();
  const commonStore = useCommonStore();
  Loading.show({
    message: t('login.loadingMsg'),
  });
  try {
    const userCredential = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
    this.uid = userCredential.user.uid;
    this.isAuthenticated = true;
    Sentry.setUser({ id: this.uid, email: email });
    await guestStore.getUserDataOnce(userCredential.user.uid);
    await commonStore.getHotelRules()
    const checkInIsDone = guestStore.userData.checkinIsDone;
    Loading.hide();
    if (checkInIsDone) {
      this.router.push({name: 'dashboard'})
    } else {
      this.router.push({name: 'checkin'})
    }
  } catch (e:any) {
    Loading.hide();
    // await saveErrorLog(commonStore.hotel, this.uid, 'doLogin', e);
    let message = '';
    switch (e.code) {
      case 'auth/wrong-password':
        message = t('auth.wrong_password');
        break;
      case 'auth/user-not-found':
        message = t('auth.user_not_found');
        break;
      case 'auth/user-disabled':
        message = t('auth.user_disabled');
        break;
      default:
        message = t('general.error', { errorMessage: e });
    }
    Notify.create({
      type: 'negative',
      icon: 'mdi-alert',
      message: message,
      actions: [
        {
          label: t('general.ok'),
          color: 'white'
        },
      ],
    });
  }
},


onBeforeMount(async () => {
  onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
    authStore.isAuthenticated = !!user;
    if (user) {
      authStore.uid = user.uid;
      authStore.isAuthenticated = true
      try {
        await commonStore.getHotelRules()
        guestStore.getUserData(user.uid)
      } catch (e) {
        Notify.create({
          type: 'negative',
          icon: 'mdi-alert',
          message: 'An error happened while fetching misc data, please let us know about this error.',
          actions: [
            {
              label: 'Ok',
              color: 'white',
              handler: () => {
                /* ... */
              },
            },
          ],
        });
      }
    } else {
      authStore.isAuthenticated = false
      guestStore.listeners.userData()
      localStorage.clear();
      sessionStorage.clear();
    }
  });
})

The upload task is performed far after all this auth process... and as I said, this happens randomly, not all users are experiencing this error.
Actually I haven't been able to replicate it, even the users with the problem I can log-in to their accounts and can't replicate it.

Add a line to log the current user's uid immediately before the call to upload to storage. What do you find in the log if the upload fails with that error?  Note that a user is not immediately considered signed in when a page loads. It takes some time for the SDK to load and possibly validate their token.  You should use an auth state observer to know when the user is actually signed in, and only then perform operations on Firebase that require auth. This is by far the most common mistake.

@DougStevenson it's indeed showing the current user's uid, and the user is authenticated because actually the auth state observer is set to kickoff the user from the app if it's not authenticated, as I said, the users are performing other operations that requires to be authenticated.
The onAuthStateChanges it's doing it's work as it should.

An update, after some more deep digging, I just found out that the problem was related to an emailUpdate action performed in the app flow.
Basically when my users log-in for the first time, the app will ask them for their email, (the users are randomnly generated with a dummy email and password), so since this operation should be done when the user has logged in recently, I ask for the email right when they log in, and proceed to update the email, but appearently if the user changes the email, the JWT token (as far as I understand) will change, and even when some operations can be done without reauthenticating, some will not, so my next step right after the Email Update operation was to reautenthicate the user with the new credentials.
In order to acomplish this, I ask the user not only for their email, but also ask for a new password, and do the whole update and reautentication at the moment the user provides it.
So far seems like this mitigated the problem.
In case anyone goes trhough this same problem, make sure you reauthenticate the user after you update their email or password.
